# Check availability of file on web python using ftb

Tags: python-3.x, file, ftp

I'm trying to write a python code that checks if a file is available using ftp

Can anyone help me with that please

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
from ftplib import FTP 
ftp = FTP('server')
ftp.login('username', 'password')

file_name = 'myfilename'
if file_name in ftp.nlst():
    print("File exists")
```

Comment: This helped a lot , Thank you so much

Comment: While this work, it can be pretty inefficient, particularly when there are lot of files in the folder. Not to mention that is involves opening a separate data connection.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test an existence of one specific file, use a method like [`FTP.size`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.size). It returns a size, when the file exists and throws an exception otherwise.

```
try:
    ftp.size(filename)
    print("file exists")
except:
    print("file does not exist or error")
```